# Do Hotel receipts in England show number of guests?

Tags: bookings, hotels, solo-travel, england

I need to go somewhere for a conference, and my company will cover the expenses. I would like to bring someone along with me, although the company might be a bit funny about me doing so, even if the cost stays within the budget.

On the other hand, the hotel might be a bit funny about me booking for one person and turning up with two.

If I was to book for two people, would the number of guests appear on the receipt/invoice, or would it just say "one room"?

Comment: Depends on the hotel, but most don't list number of guests, just room charge.

Comment: What country is this about?

Comment: @ventsyv England

Comment: In the US hotel bills do not include the number of guests, not sure about England.

Comment: @Dorothy Should be tagged "England" no?

Comment: In the US it's not customary to include the number of guests on hotel bill, might be able to ask to be included though. Might be different in England, thus the tag.

Comment: @Dorothy I think a country tag is relevant as some countries are more likely to charge per person versus per room.

Comment: @mkennedy that's valid; do you want to add it back?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hotel receipts do not usually indicate the number of guests; however, they *do* usually state the **type of room**, and this in turn often (but not always) reveals the type of bed.  So there is a theoretical possibility that somebody will wonder why you're staying in a "double room" or "king room" when everyone else is in a "single", although this seems a bit much even for a nosy accounting department.  Also, in many better hotels a queen/king bed is standard even for single travellers.

All that said, I would advise you to be upfront with the company and just **ask your boss** if it's OK to bring along your partner, naturally offering to pay for the flights and any difference in the cost of the hotel.  Most companies will not object, and this is, quite literally, a small price to pay compared to the potential reputational damage of the company finding out you did this surreptitiously and thinking that (say) the conference was only an excuse to go on a romantic holiday on the company dime.

Comment: "potential reputational damage" v nice. Important to stress too

Comment: In most cases, the double/single portion will not be a problem. Many, if not most hotels charge MORE for a single room than for a double if only for the potential of selling an extra breakfast. Therefore, booking a double for single travelers is just good business sense in most cases.

Comment: @djclayworth loads in the UK do

Comment: @djclayworth And so do Japanese hotels.

Comment: Many hotels DO show the number of guests.  eg, all 4 of my recent stays in the UK (2 in London, 1 Glasgow, 1 Edinburgh) all show it.  eg, http://i.imgur.com/QUwL851.png

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone's wondering - no, the receipt didn't show the number of guests.

Either way, I'm glad I went with @jpatokal's advice and was upfront about it with my company - they were absolutely fine with it. I would encourage anyone else in the same situation to do the same!